# How to web scrape to find out new updates on website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I know it's a broad question, but I'm looking for ideas to go about doing this. Not looking for the exact coded answer, but a rough gameplan of how to go about this!

I'm trying to scrape a blog site to check for new blog posts, and if so, to return the URL of that particular blog post.

There are 2 parts to this question, namely

1. Finding out if the website has been updated
2. Finding what is the difference (new content)

I'm wondering what are the approaches I could go about doing this. I have been using Selenium for quite a bit, and am aware that with the Selenium driver I could check for 1. with `driver.page_source`.

Is there a better way to do both 1 and 2 together, and if possible even across various different blog sites (thinking whether it is possible to write more general code applied to various blogposts at once, not a customs script for each post)?

Bonus: Is there a way to do a "diff" on the before and after of the code to see the difference, and extract necessary information from there?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to know if pages have been added or deleted, you can either look at directly, or build yourself a copy of a [sitemap.xml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) file. If they do not have a sitemap.xml, you can crawl the menu and navigation for the site and build up your own from that. Sitemap files have a 'last modified' entry. If you know the interval you are scraping on, you can calculate rather quickly if the change occurred within the interval. This is good for site-wide changes.

Alternatively, you can also check the site-header to determine the last modified time for the page. Apply the same interval check as the site-map and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the last modified value in the web sites header:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified

Comment: Hey thanks for the link! Could you explain more about how to use it? Could it be found on every site?

Comment: It should be auto generated for every website. Just send some HTTP requests and you could look up in the response header if there is a "Last-Modified" tag. 

Should look like [this](https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/cdn-uploads/20191106103944/last_modified.png).